Monster-free Formulation of Forking and Independence?
Most definitions of non-forking extensions of complete types (or independence relation) involve the use of the monster model, even in equivalent formulations (e.g. defining forking from dividing, heirs/coheirs). I know in $\omega$-stable theories we can use equality of Morley ranks (or U-ranks?), but even that involves the use of a saturated model.
I would like to know is: What role is the monster model playing here? While most books state it's merely a technical convenience, I've never seen a monster-free formulation of non-forking/independence. Is it possible, or too complicated to state? (I know we can use Morley rank in the $\omega$-stable case, but ideally I'd like to stay in the base model without going to an elementary extension.)
(For context, let's assume the theory is complete and stable, or even $\omega$-stable.)

You (usually) just have to replace "there exists in the moster model" with "there exists in some elementary extension" and "for all in the moster model" with "for all in every elementary extension".
For example, using the monster model convention, we say:

The formula $\varphi(x;b)$ divides over $A$ if there exists $(b_i)_{i\in \omega}$ and $k\in \omega$ such that $\operatorname{tp}(b_i/A) = \operatorname{tp}(b/A)$ for all $i\in \omega$ and $(\varphi(x;b_i))_{i\in \omega}$ is $k$-inconsistent (i.e., every set of $k$ formulas from this family is inconsistent).
The formula $\psi(x;c)$ forks over $A$ if there are formulas $\varphi_1(x;b_1),\dots,\varphi_n(x;b_n)$ such that $\models \forall x\, (\varphi(x;b)\to \bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_n(x;b_n))$ and each $\varphi_i(x;b_i)$ divides over $A$.

Translating this to avoid the monster model, we obtain the following:

Let $M\models T$, $b\in M$, and $A\subseteq M$. The formula $\varphi(x;b)$ divides over $A$ if there exists an elementary extension $M\preceq N$, $(b_i)_{i\in \omega}\in N$ and $k\in \omega$ such that $\operatorname{tp}(b_i/A) = \operatorname{tp}(b/A)$ for all $i\in \omega$ and $(\varphi(x;b_i))_{i\in \omega}$ is $k$-inconsistent (i.e., every sequence of $k$ formulas from this family is inconsistent).
Let $M\models T$, $b\in M$, and $A\subseteq M$. The formula $\psi(x;c)$ forks over $A$ if there exists an elementary extension $M\preceq N$ and formulas $\varphi_1(x;b_1),\dots,\varphi_n(x;b_n)$ with $b_1,\dots,b_n\in N$ such that $N\models \forall x\, (\varphi(x;b)\to \bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_n(x;b_n))$ and each $\varphi_i(x;b_i)$ divides over $A$.

As you can see, in this case, the translation isn't much more complicated than the version in the monster model. If you're unclear about how to follow this pattern to translate other definitions of forking, let me know. But note:

There's an implicit claim here that should be checked: the notion of dividing/forking over $A$ doesn't depend on the choice of model $M$ containing $A$ and $b$.

If we unpack the definition of dividing embedded in the definition of forking, we end up further quantifying over elementary extensions of elementary extensions of $M$. This gets more complicated when we have quantifier alternations in a definition, which turn into alternating quantifiers over elementary extensions of $M$. And then some definitions (upon unpacking) require us to make sure diagrams of elementary extensions commute...


The monster model allows us to sweep all this under the rug.

Thanks a lot for the explanation! Guess I see to some extent why people prefer monsters...

As long as you're only dealing with definable stuff, you can typically replace "in every elementary extension" by "in some $\aleph_0$-saturated elementary extension".
